# Should we merge the simulator and flight-simulator tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Right now we have two simulator tags:

- [flight-simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-simulator) has [33 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-simulator)
- [simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator) has has [12 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator)

There doesn't seem to be any obvious reason to have both. Should we merge them, and if so, into what?

Comment: The [tag:simulator] tag no longer has any questions: It has been split to [tag:flight-simulator] and [tag:atc-simulator].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the existence of [What regulations exist for ATC real time RADAR simulator software?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14405/what-regulations-exist-for-atc-real-time-radar-simulator-software) and [Where can I find an ATM simulation software to investigate traffic flow capacities?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/where-can-i-find-an-atm-simulation-software-to-investigate-traffic-flow-capaciti) I've created a new ATC-Simulator tag for ATC simulation software.

If there are no strong objections I'm going to start gradually re-tagging questions out of [simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator) into [atc-simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atc-simulator) and [flight-simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-simulator) as appropriate.
This will eventually kill the "simulator" tag and leave us with two distinct and non-meta tags for the most common types of simulators people will ask about.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest merging them to [simulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator), since there are other kinds of simulators (e.g. ATC simulator) as well.

Comment: I would see this as an argument to merge the other way (making the tag [tag:flight-simulator] and killing [tag:simulator]): If someone asks a question about an ATC simulator it should logically be tagged [tag:atc-simulator] and not just [tag:simulator] (and certainly not [tag:flight-simulator]).